# Seg Fault when allocating memory and setting values to 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, strcpy

I want to create an array of 26 word arrays (to sort my lists of words by first letter) so I believe I allocated memory accordingly but when I try a test run and attempt to set a random word, "hi", to each spot which must have a word, it only works for the first 5 letters then returns a set fault. Pardon my code or description, I'm quite the beginner. HELP

Note: both my parameters are defined in external functions, wordArray is the array of words in a given text file, numWordsPerLetter is an integer array which holds the number of words that start with each letter of the alphabet.

```
char*** create_alphabetical_array(char** wordArray, int* numWordsPerLetter){

  char*** alphabeticalArrays;
  int i, j;

  alphabeticalArrays = malloc(sizeof(char**)*26);
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    printf("%d\n", numWordsPerLetter[i]+1);
    alphabeticalArrays[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numWordsPerLetter[i]+1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < (numWordsPerLetter[i]+1); j++){
      printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, numWordsPerLetter[i]+1); /* using to help debug */
      strcpy(alphabeticalArrays[i][j], "hi");
    }
  }

  return (alphabeticalArrays);
}
```

Comment: `malloc(26)` should be `malloc(26 * sizeof(char**))`.

Comment: As for your problem don't forget that the size provided to [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is the size in *bytes*, not something abstract as "elements".

Comment: @Blaze I had that before but it gave me a seg fault after the first iteration of the 2nd for loop, this way still gets me through 5 iterations before the seg fault

Comment: It looks like you forgot a `malloc` on the last dimension

Comment: regarding: `char*** alphabeticalArrays;` and similar statements:  Please read [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 1):

At least these 2 errors:

Wrong element size and wrong `n`.  `alphabeticalArrays[i]` is a `char **`, so `sizeof(int)` is amiss.  `element_size * numWordsPerLetter[i]+1` should be `element_size * (numWordsPerLetter[i]+1)`

Better to use `p = malloc(sizeof *p * n)`, then `p = malloc(sizeof *(type-of p) * n)`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// alphabeticalArrays[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*numWordsPerLetter[i]+1);
alphabeticalArrays[i] = malloc(sizeof alphabeticalArrays[i][0] * (numWordsPerLetter[i]+1));
//                             ^---Element size--------------^   ^-------------N--------^
```

---

`strcpy(alphabeticalArrays[i][j], "hi");` fails because  `alphabeticalArrays[i][j]` is not assigned a pointer to allocated memory for the *string* `"hi"`. [@Zelnes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927420/seg-fault-when-allocating-memory-and-setting-values-to-3d-array/59927688#comment105977130_59927420)

```
alphabeticalArrays[i][j] = malloc(strlen("hi") + 1);
```

Alternative: research `strdup()`.

---

Robust code would also check if the allocations succeeded.

```
p = malloc(n);
if (p == NULL) Handle_Failure();
```

Comment: @NathanDrake  Note the "At least this error:".  The changes "works", it is just that code has additional problems.

Comment: I tried fixing the first problem using the format u recommended, would u say its appropriate? because I wish to allocate enough memory for the character arrays (arr[0][0], arr[0][1], etc.) of each letter array (arr[0], arr[1]) as given by the int array argument

Comment: @NathanDrake Yes.  Also consider `alphabeticalArrays = malloc(sizeof(char**)*26);` --> `alphabeticalArrays = malloc(sizeof *alphabeticalArrays * 26);`.